# Working with file streams generically

Tags: c++, file-io, generic-programming

I want to work with file streams generically. That is, i want to 'program to an interface and not the implementation'. Something like this:

```
  ios * genericFileIO  = new ifstream("src.txt");
  getline(genericFileIO, someStringObject);//from the string library; dont want to use C strings
  genericFileIO  = new ofstream("dest.txt");
  genericFileIO -> operator<<(someStringObject);
```

Is it possible? I am not great with inheritance. Given the io class hierarchy, how do i implement what i want?

Comment: you want to implement your own stream class hierarchy or you want to figure out how to use C++ stream classes?

Comment: I though the C++ stream classes were interfaces.

Answer (score 2):

Do you mean:

```
void
pass_a_line(std::istream& in, std::ostream& out)
{
  // error handling left as an exercise
  std::string line;
  std::getline(in, line);
  out << line;
}
```

This can work with anything that is an `std::istream` and `std::ostream`, like so:

```
// from a file to cout
// no need to new
std::ifstream in("src.txt");
pass_a_line(in, std::cout);

// from a stringstream to a file
std::istringstream stream("Hi");
std::ofstream out("dest.txt");
pass_a_line(stream, out);
```

This does what your example do, and is programmed against the `std::istream` and `std::ostream` interfaces. But that's not generic programming; that's object oriented programming.

Boost.Iostreams can adapt classes to `std::[i|o|io]stream`s, and does this using generic programming.

Comment: Thats ok. Clever use of a generic function. But what i really want to do is something like in the question. Program to an interface. I mean given the io class hierarchy, shouldn't it be possible to do so?

Comment: @Abhi It's not a generic function, and one of the use of `std::istream` and `std::ostream` is to be a base class. In my function, they *are* considered interfaces.

Answer (score 1):

You can use different specialisations of the ostream or istream concepts over the ostream or istream interface.

```
void Write(std::ostream& os, const std::string& s)
{
    os << "Write: " << s;
}

std::string Read(std::istream& is)
{
    std::string s;
    is >> s;
    return s;
}

int main()
{
    Write(std::cout, "Hello World");

    std::ofstream ofs("file.txt");
    if (ofs.good())
        Write(ofs, "Hello World");

    std::stringstream ss;
    Write(ss, "StringStream");
    Write(std::cout, ss.str());


    std::string s = Read(std::cin);
    Write(std::cout, s);

    return 0;
}
```